# DAX - Sum of filtered categories

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table in power bi called transaction. demonstrated below

| merchant | transaction_type | sales_representative | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Merchant_A | reload | Adam | 250 |
| Merchant_B | in-person | null | 100 |
| Merchant_C | reload | Adam | 50 |
| Merchant_C | reload | Adam | 100 |
| Merchant_B | reload | Daniel | 200 |
| Merchant_A | reload | Adam | 50 |
| Merchant_A | in-person | null | 150 |

I am want my visual table to look like below

Selected Representative by Slicer : Adam

| merchant | total_reload | total_Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Merchant_B | 0 | 100 |
| Merchant_C | 150 | 0 |
| Merchant_A | 300 | 150 |

**total_reload :- is the sum(amount) where transaction_type  = 'reload'

total_Sales  :- is the sum(amount) where transaction_type <> 'reload'**

I have tried to create two measures
TotalReload =  where they sum(amount) if transaction_type  = 'reload'
TotalReload =  where they sum(amount) if transaction_type  <> 'reload'

it works fine, as long as the slicer is not applied. The moment I choose i.e Adam as sales_representative from the slicer, then the value of total_Sales is zero for all merchants, I know this is because when transaction_type <> 'reload' then sales_representative is empty for that transaction.

What should i do to have a result table like above, where the slicer filters out the corresponding merchants, and for each merchant i should have total_sale calculated for each merchant even though sales_representative = null because the transaction_type is 'in-person' ?

Comment: If you want to remove part of a filter use a pattern like this
CALCULATE([measure],ALL('DimensionTable'[ColumnName]) )

where 'DimensionTable'[ColumnName] is the column you want removed from the evaluation context (basically, it means that the evaluation engine will ignore the filter and include the records anyway).